# How can I use Javascript library in R language via "V8" packages?

Tags: javascript, r, v8

I want to use RiTa.js in R language, but my code does not load the right library. How can I fix it?

Script

```
library(V8)

ct <- v8()

ct$source("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rita/1.1.51/rita-full.js")


ct$eval("var s = 'it was a dark and stormy night.';")

ct$eval("var r = new RiString(s);")
```

Result

```
Error in context_eval(join(src), private$context) : ReferenceError: RiString is not defined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will just need to make a slight adjustment to get this up and running.  The RiTa JavaScript expects to be in the browser with `window` available.  The default in R `V8` is `global`.  Fortunately we can easily change with `global="window"` argument.

```
library(V8)

ctx <- v8(global="window")
ctx$source("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rita/1.1.51/rita-full.js")
ctx$get("Object.keys(window)")
```

You should now see all the RiTa.js available for use.

```
  [1] "console"      "print"        "window"       "ArrayBuffer" 
  [5] "Int8Array"    "Uint8Array"   "Int16Array"   "Uint16Array" 
  [9] "Int32Array"   "Uint32Array"  "Float32Array" "Float64Array"
 [13] "DataView"     "_RiTa_LTS"    "RiTa"         "RiString"    
 [17] "RiGrammar"    "RiMarkov"     "RiWordNet"    "RiLexicon"   
 [21] "RiTaEvent"
```